# How to fetch only files of certain extensions from SVN repository?

Tags: linux, svn

My SVN repository contains a lot of files of many different types. I'd like to have a local copy of the whole repository, but containing just files of specified extensions (preserving file paths).

Is it possible to only fetch these specified files when checking out (file system size limitations), instead of downloading all files and then removing the unnecessary ones?

This is more or less how the repository structure looks like in the central repo:

```
product_blue
  + src
    - app.js
    - e404.htm
    - error.log
    - index.html
    - template.htm

product_green
  + templates
    - backup.tar.gz
    - option1.htm
    - option1a.htm
    - tests.txt
  + sources
    - index.html
    - main.js
    - not_found.txt
    - template.htm
  + working
    - e404.htm
    - form.js
    - index.html
```

And this is what I'd like to be stored locally (just the .js and .html files):

```
product_blue
  + src
    - app.js
    - index.html

product_green
  + sources
    - index.html
    - main.js
  + working
    - form.js
    - index.html
```

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this? I have the luxury of starting the synchro from scratch, so there's no existing local copy yet.

Comment: Yes it's possible using "sparse checkout". You can select which files or directories your working copy has to include. https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html